# Groovy - JAVA_HOME not set and cannot find javac

Tags: groovy, installation, setuptools

I am trying to install Groovy on windows using WSL.
After installing [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/install), I run

```
$ sdk install groovy

Downloading: groovy 3.0.9

In progress...

############################## 100.0%

Installing: groovy 3.0.9
Done installing!

Setting groovy 3.0.9 as default.
```

Then I want to check, if it works, but i got this.

```
$ groovy -version
groovy: JAVA_HOME not set and cannot find javac to deduce location, please set JAVA_HOME.
```

- **Do you know where the sdk installs groovy?**
- **Should I install anything else?**
- How to set path to JAVA_HOME?

I found only very old (6-7 years) post on this topic.
Additionally, I want to use vscode as editor/IDE. Do you recommend any plugins?

Comment: I found it. All it takes is `sdk install java` and the rest is taken care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Java in host then you need to export the environment variable correctly or else you need to install Java in WSL.